# How to install a game?

Tags: software-installation

Is it possible to install NFS carbon on Ubuntu? If so can you tell me how ? I have the setup.exe for the bonus edition of the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to run it on an emulator such as [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/). You can see a similar thread regarding NFS on Linux [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=8714).

Here is a [Youtube video indicating how to play the game on Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HZRkvw_-fM).

If you want, we can expand on how to use PlayOnLinux if unsure.

Comment: Does POL have carbon ?

Comment: @Adi yes, based on my link it does!